# How to autowire different implementations of an interface which are dependent on each other?

Tags: java, spring

I am very new to Spring and just got assigned to work on a Spring/Java project.

SftpAccessPoint has an interface as a field ( mCertificateRepository ). This field gets wired in a method inside a static inner class ( DependencyProvider) like below.

```
public class SftpAccessPoint {
         private static CertificateRepository mCertificateRepository;

         public static class DependencyProvider {
            @Autowired
            public void setCertificateRepository(final CertificateRepository pCertificateRepository) {
            SftpAccessPoint.mCertificateRepository = pCertificateRepository;
        }
    }
}
```

relavant beans are configured like below:

```
<bean id="certificateRepositoryImpl" class="com.full.appservices.impl.CertificateRepositoryImpl" /> 
<bean class="com.connector.sftp.accesspoint.SftpAccessPoint$DependencyProvider" />
```

Things function fine when the app is deployed on app server, however a few methods in CertificateRepositoryImpl don't work while running our integration tests since there is no app server running in that context.

So I wrote another implementation of CertificateReposity that implements those few methods differently and delegates the rest of the methods to the other implementation like below :

```
public class MockCertificateRepository implements CertificateRepository {

    protected CertificateRepository mCertificateRepo = null;

    public MockCertificateRepository(CertificateRepository certificateRepo) {
        mCertificateRepo = certificateRepo;
    }

    public boolean canDeactivateCertificate() {
        return mCertificateRepo.canDeactivateCertificate();
    }

    public void downloadDefaultSSHKey(OutputStream arg0, boolean arg1) {
        // a new implementation
    }
}
```

I assume i need to put a few annotations in the code and create an xml with Bean config for my test context. How can i achieve the following? :

1. Wire CertificateRepositoryImpl into the constructor of MockCertificateRepository
2. Wire MockCertificateRepository in SftpAccessPoint

*I have removed all irrelevant lines from code listings above.

*I highly prefer not to change SftpAccessPoint, unless there is no other good option

Answer (score 0):

Spring has the notion of profiles. This means that you can specify that different sets of beans are loaded into the application context depending on an app setting. The full doc is here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html. But essentially, you can have a separate set of been definitions per environment. In your case something like this:

```
<beans profile="test">
<bean id="certificateRepositoryImpl" class="...MockCertificateRepository" /> 
</beans>
<beans profile="production">
<bean id="certificateRepositoryImpl" class="...CertificateRepositoryImpl" /> 
</beans>
<beans profile="common"/>
```

And those are turned on in your application.properties like this:

```
spring.profiles.active=dev,common
```

or

```
spring.profiles.active=production,common
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your test application context configuration.

```
<bean class="com.connector.sftp.accesspoint.SftpAccessPoint$DependencyProvider" />

<bean id="mockCertificateRepository" class="com.full.appservices.impl.MockCertificateRepository"> 
   <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="certificateRepositoryImpl" class="com.full.appservices.impl.CertificateRepositoryImpl" />
   </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```